# Increase hit area for UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to have a UITableView that is in grouped style that takes up around 70% of the width of the iPad, as 100% just doesn't look good. This means there's around 150px either side.

This is fine, but I want to have the whole width of the screen available to scroll.

I've tried all sorts of mucking around with the content view and insets, etc, such as:

```
self.theTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 150, 0, 150);
self.theTable.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.theTable.contentSize.width + 300,  self.theTable.contentSize.height);
self.theTable.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-150, 0);
```

But I can't make it work like I want to.

I need to be able to tap the background on either side (the 150px or so) and be able to scroll the table view by dragging there.

Essentially, I guess this equates to either increasing the scroll view size by 150px either side, or insetting the tableview 150px either side.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `hitTest:withEvent:` method of tableView's superview and return tableView for desired points.

Alternatively you can override `hitTest:withEvent:` in tableView and check conditions there.

An example of containers superview hitTest method. All events will be forwarded to tableView.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (![self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return nil;
    }
    UITableView *tableView = nil;
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            tableView = v;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!tableView) {
        return self;
    }

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(tableView.frame, point)) {
        return [tableView hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:tableView] withEvent:event];
    } else {
        return tableView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. THanks @Evgenly Shurakov. 
For those trying to implement this, you'll need to either add this to the superview (ie UIView not UIViewController). For me, this meant creating a new object of subclass UIView, paste the above code in, and then select this class in Interface builder. Works a treat.

Comment: As a follow up (not sure if this should be a new question?), I have a subclassed UIButton that was working just fine inside the UITableView, but since the override, it's not working (not surprisingly), as I assume I'm simply passing the hit from the button to the table so it will scroll. I've tried testing for pointInside:withEvent:, but it doesn't seem to register. The class hierarchy is UITableView->TFButtonCell->UITableViewCellContentView->TFButton.

Comment: Right, I edited the code. The idea is that you should actually pass event next to tableView, when you tap exactly on it, so it could determine what to do with action.